# Parallel programming using GPU in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gpu

Could someone provide an example of using an up-to-date package how one might effectively use the GPU in parallel programming [using R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)? It is nice to know what in theory is [possible](http://www.nvidia.com/object/what-is-gpu-computing.html), but who has a practical example?

Comment: Several examples for R + GPU in [here](http://www.parallelr.com/blog/).

Answer (score 4):

Please see the [CRAN Task View on High-Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) for an edited list of packages doing just that.

Comment: I am aware of the list (it is a source in my question), is it not okay to ask for examples here?

Comment: We generally prefer questions which show a little bit of effort. I do not (yet?) see that in yours.

Comment: @Dualinity From the off-topic page: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: My main issue is that I cannot use my GPU, but I am still interested in applications.